# Run ansible playbook in role with specific playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I need run one playbook in main playbook with another `hosts file` e.g:

```yaml
- hosts: starter
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: start playbook2
    shell: |
       ansible-playbook -b -i host-cluster.txt  install-cluster.yaml 
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

it's ok and run my playbook, but I know this structure is not correct! also, I need when  `playbook2` started I see result `palybook2` in terminal, but I only see

```
TASK [install-cluster : Run task1 ] *******************************
```

I want to see result `task1` in terminal.

**Update**:

I need run one `role` with specific file `( install-cluster.yaml)`  and with specific `inventory hosts file` `(host-cluster.txt)`.

something like this:

```
- name: start kuber cluster
  include_role:
    name:kuber
    tasks_from: cluster.yml
    hosts: kuber-hosts.txt
```

Comment: This all looks like a pure [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info). For which reason exactly to you need to spawn a new `ansible-playbook` run from within a playbook? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Please do not reply in comments, edit your question to give more background information.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/ansible-tutorial.html

Comment: Load both inventories at the same time and target different group(s)/host(s) in different plays.

Answer (score 0):

You can load several inventories at once and then target different group(s)/host(s) in different plays. Just as an idea, you could have the following pseudo `your_playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Play1 does some stuff on starter hosts
  hosts: starter
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: do a stuff on starter servers
      debug:
        msg: "I did a thing"

- name: Play2 starts cluster on kuber hosts
  hosts: kuber
  
  tasks:
    - name: start kuber cluster
      include_role:
        name: kuber
        tasks_from: cluster.yml

- name: Play3 does more stuff on starter hosts
  hosts: starter

  tasks:
    - name: do more stuff on starter servers
      debug:
        msg: "I did more things"
```

You can then use this playbook with two different inventories at once if this is how you architectured it:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/starter -i inventories/kuber your_playbook.yml
```